# hide the author information from the non-member

Tags: 7, theming, nodes

I use Drupal-7.14 and the default theme,Bartik 7.14.
I added "my content type" as a new content type.
Then I could see a new content foo by the url hostname/content/foo.

The content foo shows the author and the date
because I checked

Structure > Content Types > my content type > edit > Display Settings > Display author and date information.

Only the date should be shown from logouted users.
The author should NOT be shown for logouted users.

How can I hide the author information from the non-member.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you copy the `node.tpl.php` file from the templates directory and create a `node--mycontenttype.tpl.php` file you should see the following around line 91:

```
<?php if ($display_submitted): ?>
  <div class="meta submitted">
    <?php print $user_picture; ?>
    <?php print $submitted; ?>
  </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Simply change it to this:

```
<?php if ($display_submitted): ?>
  <div class="meta submitted">
    <?php print $user_picture; ?>
    <?php if ($logged_in == TRUE): ?>
      <?php print $submitted; ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
  </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

The `$logged_in` variable is a node template variable that has the value of TRUE if a user is logged in.

In this snippet you're just saying if the user is logged in, then display the submitted information.

Don't forget to clear your caches!

**EDIT**

Apologies, I've read the question properly now.  The following should do what you want.

```
<?php if ($display_submitted): ?>
  <div class="meta submitted">
    <?php print $user_picture; ?>
    <?php if ($logged_in == TRUE): ?>
      <?php print $submitted; ?>
    <?php else: ?>
      <?php print $date; ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
  </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

This will display the entire submitted by text for authenticated users, and just the date for anonymous users.

Comment: Thanks a lots for your kind answer. "print $submitted" may include the posted date. I hate only username. Please show me  how to hide username without erasing the date.

Comment: I've noticed that your answer has almost met my question. I could use $name and $date instead of $submitted in node--mycontenttype.tpl.php file. Thank you very much again.

Comment: Awesome, I've edited the answer to reflect this so it's easier for other people in the future.  Don't forget to mark the answer as accepted if it worked for you :-)

Answer (score -1):

In D7 navigate to *admin/people/permissions*

Find **View user profiles** permissions and grand it as you wish to be.

Comment: admin/people/permissions > User > View user profiles,I tried it,the first check off,the second and the third checks on, but an author name was not hidden.I will continue waiting for other solutions.

Comment: Which theme you're using?

Comment: I use Drupal-7.14 and the default theme,Bartik 7.14.